# Can I see public data about visits and page views for Gaming?

Tags: support, site-promotion

Is there a way we can publicly follow the growth of the site? Moderators have access to some data, but aren't allowed to share it with the rest of the community. Are there public resources to this effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure you can! Quantcast is also tracking visits to the site directly. Get yer loot here:

### http://www.quantcast.com/gaming.stackexchange.com

I suggest you switch settings to Global and Range to All.

---

Here's a small, hopefully up to date chart of views last 365, 90 and 30 days.

> [image]    [image]    [image]

...and here's an annotated graph as of November 10th 2011 and June 14th 2012 (due to Jeff's impatience):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like to see what the traffic spike is like after Skyrim, and then again for Diablo 3. Is there any chance you will be posting updated annotated graphs as these come out?

Comment: @StrixVaria Well, right now I really want to annotate all the spikes so far so that it'll be easier to identify future ones.

Comment: It'd be cool to automate this with information from data.stackexchange and see what the most popular tags were from each spike.

Comment: Its rather special that Gaming has such a predictably strong correlation with several events causing the traffic to spike. On other sites such as Apple.SE the growth correlates with new iOS versions or OSX releases, but those happen much less frequent.

Comment: @IvoFlipse Have you seen the Ask Ubuntu traffic graph? Now _those_ are spikes.

Comment: What the heck happened last month [that caused this surge?](http://www.quantcast.com/askubuntu.com) Ah, it seems: The current stable release of Ubuntu, codenamed "Oneiric Ocelot". Released on October 13th, 2011

Comment: @IvoFlipse Yeah, they got a mention in the installer as well

Comment: Wow, the effect games and (if TW2 is any indication) grants have is awesome.

Comment: Is there any way to get blog stats?  I'm curious how many views my article got.  :)

Comment: skyrim makes all the other games seem rather quaint in terms of traffic.

Comment: Btw it wasn't just christmas, we also had the hat promotion at the time

Comment: @Oak eh... hats don't really drive traffic