# Why do we need a [ludum-dare] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Minicraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minicraft) questions are beginning to appear on the site and, while reviewing, I noticed that they've also been tagged with [ludum-dare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ludum-dare).  Seeing this as being roughly equivalent to a series tag, and the Ludum Dare competition not being relevant to the questions, I was going to simply edit them out until I noticed that it's [one of our beloved moderators adding them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/42534/revisions).

Do we really need this tag?  Of the three questions tagged with it, the fact that the games were made for Ludum Dare seems pertinent to none of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prelude of the Chambered (Notch's previous Ludum Dare game) has exactly one question on it, which means the [prelude-of-the-chambered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prelude-of-the-chambered) tag itself will vanish in due time.

When the question on Minicraft was asked, I took the opportunity to hit both with [ludum-dare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ludum-dare) so that they wouldn't wind up [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

It's effectively a "platform" tag, which [Jeff Atwood has suggested](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3432/336) as being the proper way to tag games which would otherwise lose their [tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) due to singleton questions.

Comment: wait, if there are two questions with that tag, that precludes the tag from being removed. Only tags with *one* use in *six months* will be auto-removed. So why..?

Comment: @JeffAtwood - There are *two* questions with `minicraft`, *one* with `prelude-of-the-chambered`. All three are now additionally tagged `ludum-dare`.

Comment: `prelude-of-the-chambered` is pretty close to death, anyway, since the question was asked in August.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like this tag was finally removed. *(There were only four questions tagged, although it is impossible for me to tell what they were now. At least two were from [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer), and the others I think were both from [badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp).)*

I had been slowly going through tags that are missing information, and this was something I had some exposure to in the past. But alas, soon after I had made an attempt at drafting some text for the excerpt and wiki, [my suggestions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/247293) were deleted along with this tag. *Farewell, Ludum Dare!*

---

For further reading, please see the following post:

[Stop removing tags that are only used once in the last 6 months](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/53249)

Comment: Ah yeah, I removed the tag from those questions when I saw the suggested edit.