# What can we do about all those untagged questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Browsing [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) on many sites, I have seen a large plethora of questions with this tag. Many other sites I come across do not have such high numbers of this tag. For instance, Stack Overflow has 0, but Arqade has 38. Can an effort be made to clean up these tags?

I would retag these myself, but I do not have much gaming experience and fear making a mistake.

Comment: This actually plays into a larger problem. The reason questions end up [tag:untagged] is because they had been tagged with the title of a game, and then, *no other questions were ever asked using that tag*. Which means, if we fix them the easy way, the problem just comes back in a matter of weeks. Fixing them the hard way is going to require coming up with a solution that doesn't cause chaos with respect to our existing positions on platform and genre tags however. (Or somebody going through and asking a second question about every game currently causing questions to be untagged.)

Comment: Thinking on it further, until we come to a decision, we should, *at the very least*, make sure we edit those 38 questions to ensure that they refer to the game by name in the question title and body, lest they never be found and disappear into the deep web forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tags that only exist on one single question are automatically removed after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/151385). If that tag was the only tag on the question, the question is not [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

This behaviour is problematic here on Arqade as we usually only use the game name as tag for most of the questions. If nobody ever asks a second question about the game, the tag will vanish after a while.

To prevent this from happening we could

- convince SE to disable the tag deletion script here (we tried and failed)
- ask a second question about each of those games (don't see how that could work)
- [tag them with a platform tag only](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3432/4103) (I really don't like this idea, might as well leave them untagged)

If we don't do anything like that, we have to retag those questions every 6 months, which is a complete waste of our time.